# Convert Arduino 5v signal to 12v signal for servo

Tags: arduino, pwm, 12v, servo

I am by no means good at electronics or electrical stuff. I have recently got into the hobby by working on my own personal project. I want to be able to control a 12 volt servo motor that takes a 12 volt signal with an arduino PWM pin. 
I have tried using a tip120 transistor by following this tutorial: http://bildr.org/2011/03/high-power-control-with-arduino-and-tip120/ however I'm just not sure how to connect the tip120 to my servo motor.
Any suggestions?

Comment: If you aren't good then go shopping instead. It's also cheaper

Comment: You have the right idea about using a transistor to use your motor and this is a handy website to help you out. However, I would definitely **not** recommend using the TIP120 (which is an NPN transistor). BJTs are known for consuming more power. I would recommend using a FET device instead, something like an nMOS device.

Comment: (you also need a 12v power supply to drive the load as well)

Comment: Any datasheet of that 12V servo Motor?

Comment: What motor exactly is this?   What you describe is **extremely unusual** so much so that it's far more likely to be a result of confusion.  You wouldn't typically want a 12v PWM signal into a servo amp, and if you have just a bare motor without a servo amp, you'd need bidirectional PWM such as from an H-bridge, not to mention a feedback mechanism and an error amplifier (probably in software) to close the loop.

Comment: If there is no datasheet for this servo motor, then it will be difficult.

Comment: @KingDuken mind posting an answer? :)

Comment: @MatthewT53 you need to correct the problems with this question to get a meaningful answer.  Otherwise it's likely to be closed and/or downvoted.

Comment: -1 another day has passed and it seems that you have abandoned this question without ever explaining enough about what you are trying to do to make meaningful answers possible.  In doing so, you've wasted the time of everyone who tried to help.

Answer (score -1):

Connect the servo just like the light bulb is. The PWM signal on the Base of the Transistor will control your servo as if it was directly connected to the Arduino.

Comment: This is a partially good answer. However, you're missing one important thing, something that will drive the load.

Comment: This is quite unlikely to actually work, for many reasons not the least of which that the question is almost certainly mistaken.  Please consider deleting this rather than leaving it here to further confusion.

Comment: PWM signal should be sent to the Servo Motor pin(Normally it does have with Arduino connections). Not to the base of the transistor and the answer is incorrect. Please delete this.

Answer (score -1):

Actually, the title of your question is right but the chosen circuit for that need is wrong at all. That circuit won't work, because the control signal needed for a servo motor is omitted in that circuit. Servo motors do need that control when it is controlled by Arduino. The PWM signal will be sent to the servo motor and a potentiometer [mechanism](http://forums.trossenrobotics.com/tutorials/how-to-diy-128/get-position-feedback-from-a-standard-hobby-servo-3279/) is there find its current position and according to the incoming pulse, the servo motor will move to the desired position.

If you need to control the motor with 12V PWM signal, then you need a level shifter circuit of 5V PWM signal to 12V PWM signal. Here is the simple circuit for that need.

[image]

Keep in mind that this circuit inverts the logic level of the input (i.e) when an input is high, then the output will be low and vice versa.

**Output graph:**

[image]

When you see the graph, an aforementioned concept can be understood.

Actually, I have found this good circuit from [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/158827/154096) and experimented it with multisim.